# How to create a Pie Chart with MigraDoc

Tags: c#, migradoc

I keep getting this error:

```
ChartType 'Pie2D' not valid for combination of charts.
```

But can't find any proper examples/documentation.

Comment: @IlikedtheoldStackOverflow I tried with the example they provided on their wiki here's the [code](https://pastecode.io/s/ay97cp89). But I thought the title is a valid question, I'm sorry.

Comment: I see a code snippet without any `using` statements. What is the exact error message? Is it a runtime error or a compile-time error? Which Wiki are you referring to?

Comment: For a Pie chart you need a simple series. I guess adding a `Series` and an `XSeries` creates complex data that cannot be displayed in a Pie chart.

Comment: This is the [wiki](http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/). `var series = chart.SeriesCollection.AddSeries();` this is the line that gives the error, I've trying to find a way to create a single Graph and not a collection but I'm being unsuccessful. Its gives a runtime error, do you have any code that works for the purpose that you don't mind sending?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample that works with MigraDoc 1.50:

```
/// <summary>
/// Defines the charts page.
/// </summary>
public static void DefineCharts(Document document)
{
    var paragraph = document.LastSection.AddParagraph("Chart Overview", "Heading1");
    paragraph.AddBookmark("Charts");

    document.LastSection.AddParagraph("Sample Chart", "Heading2");

    Chart chart = new Chart(ChartType.Pie2D);
    chart.Width = Unit.FromCentimeter(16);
    chart.Height = Unit.FromCentimeter(12);
    Series series = chart.SeriesCollection.AddSeries();
    series.Add(new double[] { 1, 5, 11, -3, 20 });

    XSeries xseries = chart.XValues.AddXSeries();
    xseries.Add("Production", "Lab", "Licenses", "Taxes", "Insurances");
    //chart.Legend.Docking = DockingType.Right;

    chart.DataLabel.Type = DataLabelType.Percent;
    chart.DataLabel.Position = DataLabelPosition.OutsideEnd;

    document.LastSection.Add(chart);
}
```

Comment: Ty seems to be working really nice :) Legend doesn't seem to be showing will try to figure it out. Once again tysm.